# How to output each data from session to view

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have this code I just do not know how to output each item in view such as firstname, lastname and username.

```
controller

{
    $selected_users = array(
          'username' => $username,
          'firstname' => 'peter',
          'lastname' => 'Sample'
          );
    $users = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), true);
    $users[] = $selected_users;
    $this->session->set_userdata('users', json_encode($users));
    $this ->load->view('db_control\sess');
   }

view:

$username = $this->session->userdata('users');
echo $username;

but it output all of it 
output of this code is
```

[{"username":"newtest1","firstname":"newtest1","lastname":"newtest1"},{"username":"sample_beth","firstname":"sample_beth","lastname":"sample_beth"},{"username":"default","firstname":"default","lastname":"default"}]

which is right but i want to output the username, lastname and firstname but still all the record

Comment: yes it should be a list of names comin from user_data session

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass data like this
controller

```
$data['selected_users'] = array(
                        'username'  =>  'testuser',
                        'firstname' =>  'peter',
                        'lastname'  =>  'Sample'
                    );
$this->load->view('viewname',$data );
```

view:

```
echo $selected_users['username'];
echo '<br>';
echo $selected_users['firstname'];
echo '<br>';
echo $selected_users['lastname'];
```

Comment: it gives an output but only one record (it overwrite the previous selected), the data coming from user_data sessions is list of all usernames that is being selected.

Answer (score 0):

You set selected_users array in one variable. Try this:

```
controller
{
$selected_users = array(
'username' => $userID,
'firstname' => 'peter',
'lastname' => 'Sample'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($selected_users);
}

view:
echo $this->session->userdata('username');
echo $this->session->userdata('firstname');
echo $this->session->userdata('lastname');
```

Comment: but the output should be list of username not just one record

Answer (score 0):

In your view change your `code` to this :

```
$username = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), TRUE);

      foreach ($username AS $key => $value) {
              echo 'Username: ' . $value['username'];
              echo '<br/>';
              echo 'First Name: ' . $value['firstname'];
              echo '<br/>';
              echo 'Last Name: ' . $value['lastname'];
              echo '<br/><hr><br/>';  
      }
```

Basically, you are converting your `JSON` back to Array and then looping through it.

Comment: But what if i want to delete specific username in session user_data?

Comment: Inside the `foreach` loop check for the username and remove it by index.
            `foreach ($username AS $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['username'] == 'my_username')
                                unset($username[$key]);
                }
                //Reindex the array
                $username = array_values($username);                
                
                //Write the data back to the session
                $this->session->set_userdata('users', json_encode($username));`

This is not the best way, you shouldn't store this much data in a session.